# Nonetype object has no append attribute append list to dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

If i enter in `n`, a dictionary `count_dict` of size `n+1` will be created with keys `0...n`.

I want to parse through a list called `binary_list` that contains strings of size `n` that each compose of 0's or 1's. Each parse will count the number of 1's in the string and `append`each string with the number of 1's to the appropriate key

ex:

```
{0:['000'], 1:['001','010','100'] , 2:['011', '101', '110'] , 3:['111']}
```

my code to perform this:

```
count_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(0,n+1))

for element in binary_list:
    count_dict[element.count('1')].append(element)
```

error"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "facebook_prob.py", line 23, in sortbit
    count_dict[element.count('1')].append(element)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without specifying the second argument, values are None by default. (See [`dict.fromkeys`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#dict.fromkeys))

```
>>> n = 3
>>> count_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(0,n+1))
>>> count_dict
{0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

In addition to that, values created by `dict.fromkeys` are shared by all entries.

```
>>> count_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(0,n+1), [])
>>> count_dict
{0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: []}
>>> count_dict[0] is count_dict[1]
True
```

[`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is more appropriate.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> count_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> count_dict[0].append('000')
>>> count_dict[1].append('001')
>>> count_dict[1].append('010')
>>> count_dict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['000'], 1: ['001', '010']})
```